# Why doesn't my layout move up enough with "adjustPan"?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-statusbar, window-soft-input-mode, adjustpan

I had some issues using `adjustPan` in my app, as it is not working as it is supposed to do. Some other users also experienced this problem, so I think it's important to share this issue ([Layout doesn't move up enough when clicking EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47265910/layout-doesnt-move-up-enough-when-clicking-edittext)).

**Note:** I am using Android Studio **and** I'm using an "Instant App", so the location of the files are going to be a bit different.

When I use `adjustPan` in my layout, my activity does not move up enough to the point where the `EditText` appears above the Soft Keyboard (See Image For Details). The same result still appears no matter if you use it in a Manifest file or a Java file.

Not only that, but the weirdest part is that Status Bar becomes **transparent** and the dark blue bar which is supposed to go behind the notification icons goes **down** a little bit (See Image For Details).

[image: Screenshot of issue]

I have tried making several attempts of solving this issue, like using `adjustResize` and `setOnTouchListener` but both of these answers that I received didn't solve this issue.

I still can't figure out the cause of this issue, so any answers or comments regarding how to discover why this issue is happening is also fine.

Here is some of my code:

**Manifest File:**

```
<activity
        android:name=".Input_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

**Java File:**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Input_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_input__activity);

    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
   }
}
```

**XML File:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Input_Activity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="214dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.585"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.725" />
```

All feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create an object like InputMethodManager methodManager at class level.
add these lines to your `onCreate()` method,

```
methodManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

and in your onClick() method, show keyboard like,

```
methodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(
    your_view_name.getApplicationWindowToken(),
    InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

If this word **getApplicationWindowToken** throws an error then replace it with **getWindowToken**
hope it helps.

Comment: I'm a bit new to Android Studio, what is supposed to go on: `your_view_name`

Comment: Even though this is not `adjustPan` it still works overall. It would be great if you would be able to fix this with `adjustPan`

Answer (score 1):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode
```

Above attribute can be used to specify what happens with activity contents.

Below image can clear your doubts more [image]

- **adjustPan**: The activity’s main window is not resized to make room for
  the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are
  automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by
  the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is
  generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to
  close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of
  the window.
- **adjustResize**: The activity’s main window is always resized to make
  room for the soft keyboard on screen.

I think there is no need add below code which you have added.

<s>getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);</s>

Answer (score 0):

Also need to add following code in your onTouch event so that when soft keyboard appears it will go up. Example:

```
 editText.setTransformationMethod(WordBreakUtil.getInstance());
 editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Android Studio (My IDE) states that: "It cannot solve symbol `WordBreakUtil`"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the answer. but try replacing

```
<activity
    android:name=".Input_Activity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

with

```
<activity
    android:name=".Input_Activity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

in your android manifest.
[Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410528/1771375)

Hope this helps!